# Adding node to the end of linked list (C++)?

Tags: c++, linked-list, insert, nodes

My code inside int main is:

```
       node *run=NULL, *head=NULL, *temp=NULL;

   for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
   {
       temp = new node();   
       temp->value = x*10;  
       temp->next = NULL;   
       temp -> prev = NULL; 
       if (head == NULL) 
       {
           head = temp;
       }
       else
       {
           run = head;
           while (run->next != NULL)
           {
               run = run->next;
           }
           temp -> prev = run; 
           run->next = temp;   
       }
   }
   run = head;
   cout << "ORIGINAL:" << endl;
   while (run != NULL)
   {
       printf("%d\n", run->value);
       run = run->next;
   }
cout << endl << endl;
//=============== ADD AT THE END ========================
int xb = 105; //Value I want to add
run = head;

while (run -> next -> value > xb) 
{
    run = run -> next;
}
    temp = new node();
    temp ->  prev = run;
    temp -> value = xb;
    temp -> next = NULL;

    run -> next = temp;


run = head;
cout << "ADDED 105:" << endl;
while (run != NULL)
{
    printf("%d\n", run->value);
    run = run->next;
}
```

I have been trying to figure out the problem to adding the new node (105) in my code but nothing I have done seems to work. The original one works perfectly fine and outputs

```
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

but the code for insertion only outputs

```
10 105
```

instead of

```
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 105
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't allocate a new node until you position your management pointers where said-node should be inserted. your setup of `temp` below the cutline is simply wrong, and you never wire `temp->next` in correctly. And fyi, your post should include the *expected* sequence outcome as well as the failed outcome. The *prior* outcome, while interesting, isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize your `new node`, you set its `next` pointer to `NULL`:

```
temp = new node();
temp ->  prev = run;
temp -> value = xb;
temp->next = NULL;
```

Then you search through the existing list to find where to insert the new node. And then you insert it:

```
run -> next = temp;
```

If you were paying any attention, you would immediately notice that `temp`'s `next` pointer is still, very much, a `NULL`. Nothing has been done about it.

So, the pointer to the rest of the list gets lost, by the virtue of the fact that the newly-inserted node will always have `NULL` for its `next` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you shouldn't let *temp->next = NULL* when you insert an element into a link list, because you would lost your node after place where you insert into.You need to this *temp->next = run->next* to connect your node after you inserted.This is the main problem of your program.
Another problem is after you modify your code, the answer wasn't you expected:

```
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 105
```

Here's the problem

```
while (run -> next -> value > xb) 
{
    run = run -> next;
}
```

As you can see, run->next->value > xb(20>105?) was always false, so your should do this

```
while (run->value < xb && run->next != NULL) 
{
    run = run -> next;
}
```

Your initialization code of link list is pretty bad.If you want to insert a node at the tail of list, you should remember the last node each time instead of travelling the list.Consider this code:

```
node *run=NULL, *head=NULL, *temp=NULL, *last=NULL;

   for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
   {
       temp = new node();   
       temp->value = x*10;  
       temp->next = NULL;   
       temp -> prev = NULL; 
       if (head == NULL) 
       {
           head = temp;
           last = temp;
       }
       else
       {
           /*run = head;
           while (run->next != NULL)
           {
               run = run->next;
           }*/

           temp->prev = last; 
           last->next = temp;   
           last = temp;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I respect if this is a C training session. If so you have been provided excellent support.
But if you are making production code, you should use std::list instead. It may have performance penalties, but you will be relieved from debugging.

If you prefer the training mode, I would suggest you to include an end-pointer to avoid the tedious while-to-end in every 'for' iteration. This will improve performce significantly, especially with large linked lists.

Comment: While stellar advice (using the standard library containers rather than rolling their own, using an end-pointer strategy for faster end-point insertions), this doesn't address the issue(s) the OP is having with their code as-presented.